# Xcode 4 failed to launch

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4, llvm, lldb

I'm currently migrating an old OS X project from Xcode 3 GCC to Xcode 4 LLVM.

The migration has so far gone fine. I've updated the code from 10.4 to 10.6, with a lot of deprecated API, and it all compiles just fine.

But when I try do debug using LLDB, I get the following error:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/trenskow/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Famous_Web_Editor-ddfqhzdztzzgfrcxaaywyxgtahzx/Build/Products/Debug/The Famous Web Editor.app/Contents/MacOS/The Famous Web Editor'
```

The application runs fine on it's own (besides the runtime errors I am trying to debug).

When I switch back to LLVM GCC and GDB, it launches fine, but Xcode never stops at the breakpoints. The application stops, but I do not get any indication of a breakpoint is being hit by Xcode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long shot, but:

```
The Famous Web Editor
```

Xcode and the compiler can sometimes trip over spaces in the project/target name. This usually shows up in broken header or library search paths, so I'm not sure if it applies here. But it's certainly worth a try to rename the target so it contains no spaces.

Comment: Encountered a similar problem with 'Product Name' in XCode 4.3.2.
Solved by renaming Targets > Product Name to contain no spaces.

Comment: Encoubtered similar problem in XCode 4.3.2. Solved by changing the productName. Was "ImageTargets" to "QRCOM" and worked like a charm.

Comment: any other possible solution instead of renaming the productname?.

Comment: Got the issue with project needing iOS 5+, while device was 4.3

Answer (score 2):

```
First clear your DerivedData  (/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/) delete every thing from there.
```

Now restart your XCode, Restart your device.

run Xcode